# Azure AD B2C - How to map the user logged in from social IDP to a local user table?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

one of our existing projects is running with a traditional authentication logic (having a user table in database). How the plan is to move the identity to AzureB2C with social IDPs integrated. But there are still some ares where we would need the reference of the existing user table. I need to find a way to map the logged in user from Azure B2C with the user table in database. I can read the email property from claims and try to map, but the challenge is user might have a different email for his social accounts. I know this actually defeats the purpose of the openId/oAuth to look back again in the user table after login. But this is a strange situation in running into. Any ideas how best this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Copying response from: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/221fce11-28ff-4236-a300-d6160ffc9379/azure-ad-b2c-how-to-map-the-user-logged-in-from-social-idp-to-a-local-user-table-?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Some facts are missing from your question so I will make assumptions which you can correct.
Assume that:
You do not use social IDPs today.  So no existing connection between the social account and the local DB account.
This point is crucial because it is usually the user's prerogative (due to privacy) to make this link explicitly.
Assume that you will tell the user explicitly what you are doing as part of the transition.

To achieve this with b2c built-in policies you could:
1. Your app logs in the user the old fashioned way.(existing lookup DB)
2. Your app then invites users to register (in fact re-register) using a b2c signup policy which offers them social idp choices. 
3. At the end of the b2c registration process, the user's email which was provided and proofed during the b2c signup and Object ID (newly created) is sent back to the App
4. The app uses the object ID and Graph to write the users existing id (old DB email or other unique user id you used today) to the new user's object in Azure AD B2C.
5. The app should note on the old DB that this user has been migrated so in the future the app does not present the option to re-register.
6.  The app has to manage users in 2 different states.

---

Other alternative is to use custom policies and  Account Linking
Here you could 
1. Migrate all users into b2c using their old passwords. (assume you can get them from old DB in the clear) using Graph.
2. Point your app to b2c - users can login
3. Offer you users the option to link their b2c account to a social account.  this requires custom policy and a policy path that is not public but its a simple sample we can provide.